# Python json.loads ValueError, expecting delimiter

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

I am extracting a postgres table as json. The output file contains lines like:

```
{"data": {"test": 1, "hello": "I have \" !"}, "id": 4}
```

Now I need to load them in my python code using `json.loads`, but I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 33, in <module>
    print json.loads('''{"id": 4, "data": {"test": 1, "hello": "I have \" !"}}''')
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 365, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 381, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
ValueError: Expecting , delimiter: line 1 column 50 (char 49)
```

I figured out the fix is to add another `\` to `\"`. So, if I pass

```
{"data": {"test": 1, "hello": "I have \\" !"}, "id": 4}
```

to `json.loads`, I get this:

```
{u'data': {u'test': 1, u'hello': u'I have " !'}, u'id': 4}
```

Is there a way to do this without adding the extra `\`? Like passing a parameter to `json.loads` or something?

Comment: hey folks i am having same problem any valid solutuion ?

Answer (score 29):

You can specify so called “raw strings”:

```
>>> print r'{"data": {"test": 1, "hello": "I have \" !"}, "id": 4}'
{"data": {"test": 1, "hello": "I have \" !"}, "id": 4}
```

They don’t interpret the backslashes.

Usual strings change `\"` to `"`, so you can have `"` characters in strings that are themselves limited by double quotes:

```
>>> "foo\"bar"
'foo"bar'
```

So the transformation from `\"` to `"` is not done by `json.loads`, but by Python itself.

Comment: I am reading the data file line by line. So I have the dictionaries in variables.  I tried `.replace("\\", r"\\")` and `.encode('string-escape')`, neither works.

Comment: In JSON `"\""` means `'"'`, too, just like in Python. If there’s a `\"` in the input file, it actually is a `"`.  If you for some reason want to have `r'\"'` anyway, you would need `.replace('"', '\\"')`.

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

```
json.loads(r'{"data": {"test": 1, "hello": "I have \" !"}, "id": 4}')
```

If you have that string inside a variable, then just:

```
json.loads(data.replace("\\", r"\\"))
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I'm afraid it doesn't work, `'{"data": {"test": 1, "hello": "I have \" !"}, "id": 4}'` and `'{"data": {"test": 1, "hello": "I have \" !"}, "id": 4}'.replace("\\", r"\\")` are exactly the same.

Comment: @AliBZ It doesn't work because you're missing the `r` before the string. Copy and paste my first example, that will work.

Comment: I have my string inside a variable, thats why I used your second example.

Comment: @AliBZ Ok, so the unique way to do it is manually replace `"` with `\\"` using `replace`.

Answer (score 2):

Try using  triple quotes r""", no need to consider the \ thing.

```
json_string = r"""
{
    "jsonObj": []
}
"""
data = json.loads(json_string)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the ways `source.replace('""', '')`  or sub it, cause `""` in the source will make `json.loads(source)` can not distinguish them.

Answer (score 1):

for my instance, i wrote:

```
STRING.replace("': '", '": "').replace("', '", '", "').replace("{'", '{"').replace("'}", '"}').replace("': \"", '": "').replace("', \"", '", "').replace("\", '", '", "').replace("'", '\\"')
```

and works like a charm.

Comment: I dont know, why u had negative votes. I tried yours and it worked.