# Convert a text file in to a dictionary in python

Tags: python

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/epaXW.png)

I am getting value error in python while trying to convert a text file in to dictionary.

I am getting the file from an api.

```
filename=open('/sbranch/CTK/SAP/hkeep/vrp.json','r')
dictionary = {}
with open("/sbranch/CTK/SAP/hkeep/vrp.json", "r") as file:
    for line in file
        key, value = line.strip()
        dictionary[key] = value
    print(dictionary)
```

below is the error message:

```
key, value = line.strip()
```

ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack

Comment: Could you please share the content of file vrp.json. As per your code `key, value = line.strip()` each line should have two values separated by a comma like 2, Name so 2 will become key and Name will value.

Comment: {
  "type" : "taskSap",
  "actions" : {
    "abortActions" : [ ],
    "emailNotifications" : [ ],
     "setVariableActions" : [ {
      "description" : null,
      "exitCodes" : null,
      "notificationOption" : "Operation Failure",
      "notifyOnEarlyFinish" : false,
      "notifyOnLateFinish" : false,
      "notifyOnLateStart" : false,
      "status" : "Failed",
      "variableName" : "jobname",
      "variableScope" : "Global",
      "variableValue" : {""}
        }, {
      "description" : null,
      "exitCodes" : null,
      "notificationOption" : "Operation Failure"

Comment: its just begining of the file.. it has 100s of lines like this

Comment: why cant you use `json.loads()` or `json.load()`?

Comment: @Shijith, I am getting the below error when i tried with json.load()    json.loads(json_data)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 366, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
ValueError: Expecting : delimiter: line 16 column 28 (char 464)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28223242/python-json-loads-valueerror-expecting-delimiter

Comment: I am just starting to write the python code.. i am really couldn't follow the logic in the forum. Could be please give me in a simple example.. how i should read that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple function to open a json file and load it into a python dictionary:

```py
import json

def open_json(path):
    with open(path, 'r') as file:
        return json.load(file)

mydict = open_json('/sbranch/CTK/SAP/hkeep/vrp.json')
```

If you are getting the file from an api, you can actually get it directly using the requests library:

Install:

```sh
pip install requests
```

This will give you a dictionary from the json response (if there is json):

```py
import requests

url = 'enter_your_url_here'
response = requests.get(url)
mydict = response.json()
```

Comment: First code worked for me and the dictionary is created successfully. I have printed the contents of dictionary and i noticed additional character is being added. {u'systemOperations': [{u'agentClusterVar': None, u'triggerVar': None, u'taskLimitType': u'Unlimited', u'variables': [], u'agent': None, u'notifyOnLateFinish': False, u'virtualResourceVar': None, u'variablesUnresolved': False, u'operation': u'Launch Task', u'execWorkflowName': None, u'execWorkflowNameCond': u'Equals', u'execId': None, u'notifyOnLateStart': False,  not sure what is u' is meant and how can i remove that

Comment: that's unicode encoding, what version of python, what version are you using? https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#unicode-strings

Comment: I would HIGHLY recommend not using python 2.7 especially for starting a new project unless it is absolutely necessary, use python 3 instead: https://www.python.org/doc/sunset-python-2/ are you using PyCharm?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your support, i have changed to python3 shebang and it worked now.

Comment: I have converted all my python 2 development to python3 version. Thanks for your suggestion. @Tenacious B