# Python: ValueError: Expecting , delimiter: line 1 when loading json

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

`sample_json_obj = '{"foo":{"IdentityDocuments":[{"bar":"{\"baz\":\"qux\"}"}]}}'`

This is syntactically accurate for a JSON string.
However when I try to load into a variable for further processing,

`json.loads(sample_json_obj)`

I get the following stacktrace

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 5, in <module>
    json.loads(sample_json_obj)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.17_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 339, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.17_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 364, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.17_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 380, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
ValueError: Expecting , delimiter: line 1 column 40 (char 39)
```

I read through a few StackOverflow posts trying to fix this and one of the [popular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28223242/python-json-loads-valueerror-expecting-delimiter) ones suggest mutating the string to the following format

`sample_json_obj = r'{"foo":{"IdentityDocuments":[{"bar":"{\"baz\":\"qux\"}"}]}}'`

which works as expected but my only problem is that since I am getting this JSON object directly from a query and I am not able to add the r in front of it i.e convert it to a raw string although I have tried several other stack posts including trying formatting, none worked.

Can someone please help me?

Would be great if someone could help me without modifying the first line i.e

`sample_json_obj = '{"foo":{"IdentityDocuments":[{"bar":"{\"baz\":\"qux\"}"}]}}'`

Comment: If you are getting the value of the string directly from a query, then why are you dealing with a string literal at all?

Comment: let's say `sample_json_obj = get_query_result()` I am still having the same problem right? I dont understand your question.

Comment: In your Sample Json: ` ​{"bar":"{\"baz\":\"qux\"}"}
`
Do you want to keep it `bar:string` or make that dict too?

Comment: The problem is that the string is effectively malformed as far as Python is concerned. The escape characters need to be doubled - i.e. '{"foo":{"IdentityDocuments":[{"bar":"{\\"baz\\":\\"qux\\"}"}]}}'

Comment: @devReddit I want to make everything a dict as in a json object so that I can access anything with key, value combinations.

Comment: @AndyKnight I tried doing 
`sample_json_obj = (sample_json_obj.replace('\"', '\\"'))
json.loads(sample_json_obj)`
Seeing error,
`ValueError: Expecting property name: line 1 column 2 (char 1)`

Comment: Try this:- assign the string exactly as shown at the beginning of your post then print it. You'll see that the backslashes are not there. It's because the escaped double-quote is irrelevant. It would help if you could explain how you acquire these data